# new battery, full charged capacity less than designed capacity and wear level at least 7% after drain empty

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I just installed a new OEM battery to my Surface Pro 4.

The **1st-round test result** is like this:

[image]

[image]

The **2nd-round test result**:

[image]

The **3rd-round test result**:

[image]

The **4th-round test result**:

[image]

If I charge it to full. The Full Charged Capacity will be bigger than the Designed Capacity and the Wear Level will be 0.0%. It will keep the same states/numbers during the entire discharging period.

But if I discharge it to empty, The Full Charged Capacity will be less than the Designed Capacity and the Wear Level will not be 0.0%, as shown above. It will keep the same states/numbers during the entire charging period until it is full.

Is this normal? The battery is good or bad?

Comment: Although you have asked a good question, I think it can still be best answered by the manufacturer or vendor of the device.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please note that this site is for questions on _electronics design_, not just anything electronic. Sadly, that means your question is off-topic here, and will likely be closed. Perhaps our sister site [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a better fit for your question.

Comment: @marcelm I am confused. If I ask there, maybe nobody can answer it. I just checked there, there is no single question about the battery. I don't know why this is DESIGN only. I don't know how a DESIGN is not related to daily usage. A design will not be a good design if "users" are not considered, I think. User questions are valuable. Designers can get lots of useful information from those questions.

Comment: I get 12,600 hits if I [search SU for "battery"](https://superuser.com/search?q=battery). As for what's considered on-topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This site is for questions about _making_ electronics, not _using_ them. Again, see [other StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for a site that better fits your question.

Comment: OK, I am wrong. I do get some returns this time. I was searching tags on the Tags page. I probably typed something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Battery is achieving 93% of 'design' capacity. That's fine.

To reduce battery wear and degradation for longer lifespan, don't charge above 80% or let it go below 20%.

Comment: so, we should set the charger to stop charging at about 80% and we should plugin when the battery is about 20%?  But we usually charge to 100% for a longer usage time when we go out.

Comment: If you really need 100% charge then you have to do it, but if you don't then charging to 80% or less could greatly increase longevity, particulalry if you leave it that way for long periods. The battery degrades faster at higher charge level and temperature, and wears out faster with large charge/discharge excursions.